# Create random css values for position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random, margin

Is it possible to make random numbers between -100 and 600, to use as position (margin-top, margin-left) values for an element in CSS using jQuery / Javascript?

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking how to pick a random number? How to multiply a random number to the correct range? How to set CSS properties?

Comment: I don't know Javascript enough, I can modify the script, but rarely can write my own. And I don't know if it's possible to generate negative numbers with 

`Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);` 

I've read several topics on generating random values for css, but they were about colours and some other non-digit values and I can't figure out how to use that in my case.

Comment: I ask how to generate a random number between positive and negative values and insert (apply) it into CSS.

Comment: @Kostsei What's wrong with my solution so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible, use [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) for this.

See this example from MDN :

```
// Returns a random integer between min and max
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Then, you can use this function to give your elements random margins.

Example :

```
//Randomize the position of all your elements, identified by a specific class
//In case you have several items. Either, don't use the each()
$('.randomElement').each(function(){
    $(this).css({'marginTop' : getRandomInt(-100,600), 'marginTop' : getRandomInt(-100,600)});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry, but I still don't understand how to arrange this, it seems to me that it is a right way, but don't understand it enough and can't make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/pWpAB/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is.
You will need to use the random() function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp.
Then set with jQuery the attribute you want to change.
As follow:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
$("#someid").attr("margin-top",rand);
```

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/